# Global Variable giving error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
g=0
def smooth(self, a, b):
    k=0
    c = self.name[a]
    d = self.name[b]
    e,f=c,d
    while(e.get_p()!=f.get_p() and e.get_p()!=None and f.get_p()!=None):
        k+=1
        e=e.get_p()
        f=f.get_p()
    if(e.get_p==None and f.get_p()!=None):
        global g
        g+=1
        d=d.get_p()
        return self.smooth(a,d.name)
    return(k,g)
```

Ignore the functions called but in the if statement it is not updating value of g and giving an error **global name 'g' is not defined** on calling with a value.Please Help

Comment: is that all the code? Are you sure this is not inside a `class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
g=0
def smooth(self, a, b):
```

`smooth` looks like a class instance method, and that `g` therefore looks like a class variable, not a global one, so the `global` keyword won't work. Try referring to it as `MyClass.g` instead (where 'MyClass' is the actual name of your class), or `__class__.g`.

Comment: +1 for detecting an issue with a key line apparently missing. Good eye